# Creating a dynamic Polyline with Google Maps and C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps-api-3

I want to pass values from the VIEWBAG as an array of LatLons from my Model in C#. I am not sure how to dynamically loop the Viewbag array and add these cordinates to my javascript array to pass to:

```
    // Create an instance of Google map
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));

// Tell the map where to start
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(59.3324, 17.8857), 9);

// Create an array with points
var points = [
   new GLatLng(59.6919, 17.8582),
   new GLatLng(59.3030, 18.0395),
   new GLatLng(58.9789, 17.5341)
];

// Create a new polyline
var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);

// Add the polyline to the map using map.addOverlay()
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

I want to do something like the above, but without the static array.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

currently I have:

```
       var points = [];


   @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LatLons)
   {
     <text>
     points.push(new GLatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude);
     </text>
   }
```

But the google map will not show up when this is added, However the points are correctly iterated through from the viewbag data.

Comment: this line:
    points.push(new GLatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude);
should be:
    points.push(new GLatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude));

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the ViewBag, if you were to use a view model, you could use something like the following:

```
// Create an array with points
var points = [];
<% foreach (var item in Model.Coords)
   {%>
       points.push(new GLatLng(<%= item.lat %>, <%= item.lng %>));
   <%} %>
```

which should output into your view as:

```
var points = [];
points.push(new GLatLng(59.6919, 17.8582));
points.push(new GLatLng(59.3030, 18.0395));
points.push(new GLatLng(58.9789, 17.5341));
//...et cetera
```

The view data is inherently an object and doesn't support an iterator, so you would have to cast. This saves the need for the cast in the view by having a typed collection. This example could use a simple model like this:

```
public class CoordsModel 
{
    public List<CoOrd> Coords {get; set;}
}

public class CoOrd 
{
    public decimal lat {get; set;}
    public decimal lng {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i am already using a model for this view that is different from the cordinates model- thus i need to pass the data from the controller in a ViewBag. I have come up with something like this:     var firstLoc;
        var secLoc;
        var points = [];

   
   @foreach (var item in ViewBag.LatLons)
   {
     <text>
     points.push(new GLatLng(@item.Latitude, @item.Longitude);
     </text>
 }------------ But it does not running the  google map if I include this- however it does iterate through the list of LatLon data from the viewbag...

Comment: Does it throw a javascript error? In the comment you provided, you are missing a closing parenthesis on the line of script emitted in the for loop.

Comment: The issue was that, yes there was a missing bracket, but also I was calling the wrong method should be : points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(@Html.Raw(item.Latitude + "")),parseFloat(@Html.Raw(item.Longitude + ""))));