# Working offline with Google Maps

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps-api-3

I have a Windows Forms application with a `WebBrowser` control. I am using Google Maps API v3 for displaying a map on the browser control.

The map displays the path traveled using markers and polylines. The area in which the location is shown is limited (the path traveled is only in a specific area). I know that Google caches the map tiles.

Suppose the internet disconnects for a couple of minutes due to network issues, the map is visible and pan-able for the area which was traveled (and cached). But the Google Maps API will not work to place a marker. In such a situation, while the network is reconnected, how to place markers on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gmapcatcher -offline maps viewer-

> GMapCatcher is an offline maps viewer. It can display maps from many providers

Read this for the complete information  : [GMAPCATCHER](https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/)

Comment: I already mentioned that the map is visible. I need to place markers, and draw polylines on the map.

Comment: @Abhishek Read this : [Article1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997705/creating-a-dynamic-polyline-with-google-maps-and-c-sharp-net) and [Article2](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/312248/Google-Maps-Direction-API-V-Polyline-Decoder)

Comment: I want a way to draw polylines and markers without internet connection. Your suggested articles do not give any information about that.